# How to reduce spacing between antd Form.Items?

Tags: reactjs, antd

How does one reduce the amount of space between two Form.Item's in a Form?

for example in any of the antd form [examples](https://ant.design/components/form/) the spacing between a Form.Item is all the same and (to my eye) rather large.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to style the `Form.Item` component, for example with **inline-style**:

```js
// The current form item is margin 15px top.
<Form.Item style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```

Or the entire `Form` by overriding the css-class, for example with **CSS-in-JS**:

```js
// Apply style to all form
const StyledForm = styled(Form)`
  .ant-form-item {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
`;
```

Demo:

[image: Edit Q-56637063]

> Same can be achieved with `.css` file and importing it

Comment: incorrect, error placeholder is causing glitching effect

Answer (score 2):

This is also achievable by customizing the theme context object.

```
import { ConfigProvider, type ThemeConfig } from "antd";
const theme: ThemeConfig = {
    components: {
        Form: {
            marginLG: 15,
        },
}
```

Inject it into ConfigProvider context:

```
    <ConfigProvider theme={theme} {...otherConfigurations}>
        {props.children}
    </ConfigProvider>
```

Now all form items will have the same margin. The plus side is no css files were created to fix a minor issue. We have full control of the components' style using JSS, which is more reliable due to specificity.

Answer (score 1):

First find the style that is achieving what you want to override, the override it by importing custom css. Your example:

```
.ant-form-inline .ant-form-item {
  margin-right: 8px; // default is 16px
}
```